# Is it possible to show public images from Instagram by hashtag only without requiring user IDs?

Tags: api, embed, instagram, feed

I am trying to show images set to public from other users using a specific hashtag for a hotel.

Everything I am seeing allows only a single post embed or requires authorization.

I only want a hashtag feed that comes from multiple users.

For instance, embedding: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/cake/

Without requiring a separate embed for each image and without needing authorization. (Using images set to public).

Thank you!

Comment: [apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986241/embed-multiple-instagram-images-without-access-token) you now have to get an access_token..