# Embed multiple instagram images without access_token

Tags: embed, instagram, instagram-api

The instagram [docs say](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/):

> ```
> https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
> ```
>
> The Instagram API requires an `access_token` from authenticated users for each endpoint. We no longer support making requests using just the `client_id`.

But to get an `access_token`, users of my website must click through and authenticate, right?

How can I display a few pictures of a specific instagram-tag on my public website, without requiring users to sign in via their instagram-account?

(There seem to be other pages doing it somehow, is there an iframe embed that displays multiple images? I've only found one where you can display one specific image...)

Update: [This WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wd-instagram-feed/changelog/) seems to do it with having the admin (i.e. me) generate the `access_token` once and then having the page use it for all users. Any drawbacks to that approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if that `access_token` expires for some reason or instagram invalidates it, then it will stop working, you should not assume `access_token` is valid forever.

Usually it does not expire that often, so if you monitor your widget constantly and update `access_token` if it has stopped working, then you should be good.

Comment: thanks, so I've got myself an access_token with the `public_scope` but when I try e.g. `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=MYTOKEN`, the `data` in the returned JSON is always empty...?

Comment: thats correct, in live mode u will get all results, in sandbox u only get your and your sandbox users posts in API response, so if u post a photo with #nofilter then only that post will be in API response in sandbox mode